# Does the relative speed of light, or just the frequency of light, change near a planet?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, redshift

I have read this [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175403/) question that describes the red shift in frequency of light near a large planet. I'm wondering if the light will actually reach me slower.

Imagine that we have two lasers 1,000,000,000 kilometers from me.  Laser A will shine at me without passing near any large planets.  Laser B will pass through holes that we have drilled through the centre of several large planets (so there is no need for refraction, simply time dilation)  Both lasers are flashed simultaneously.

Will Laser A reach me first because it faces no extra time dilation and Laser B will reach me later because it faces gravitational time dilation.   OR, Will both lasers reach me at the same instant, but Laser B will be red shifted?

Comment: You might want to look up "Shapiro delay".

Comment: @JohnDoty  Thanks for that.   I've never heard that term before.  "In a nearly static gravitational field of moderate strength the effect may be considered as a special case of gravitational time dilation. The measured elapsed time of a light signal in a gravitational field is longer than it would be without the field, and for moderate-strength nearly static fields the difference is directly proportional to the classical gravitational potential, precisely as given by standard gravitational time dilation formulas."   Exactly what I needed.